# Raycast based on object direction with swipe gestures

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, raycasting

In my game, when the player swipe in any of the 4 directions a ray gets created from an object based on that direction, then the object rotates towards that direction:

```
void Update ()
{
    if (direction == SwipeDirection.Up)
    {
        RayTest (transform.forward)

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (Vector3.forward);
    }

    if (direction == SwipeDirection.Right)
    {
        RayTest (transform.right)

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (Vector3.right);           
    }

    if (direction == SwipeDirection.Down)
    {
        RayTest (-transform.forward)

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (Vector3.back);            
    }

    if (direction == SwipeDirection.Left)
    {
        RayTest (-transform.right)

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (Vector3.left);        
    }
}

void RayTest (Vector3 t)
{
    // "transform.position + Vector3.up" because the pivot point is at the bottom
    // Ray is rotated -45 degrees
    Ray ray  = new Ray(transform.position + Vector3.up , (t - transform.up).normalized);
    Debug.DrawRay (ray.origin, ray.direction, Color.green, 1);
}
```

The code works perfect if I don't rotate the object after every swipe, rotating it messes up the direction, so if the player swipes up and the object is looking to the right, the ray direction becomes it's forward direction which is right.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying the ray direction relative to your transform by saying i.e. `transform.right`. This means that once you rotate your transform, the meaning of `transform.right` is different from what it was before.

You didn't specify whether the camera rotates with the player, so I am assuming it doesn't. Under that assumption, `SwipeDirection.Right` always means the same direction, so `RayTest(..)` also should always test the same direction.

So I suppose you just need a constant direction like `Vector3.right` as a parameter for `RayTest(..)` instead.

Comment: Yup, changing "transform" with "Vector3" definitely did it. Thank you.